# How to properly display the checked attributes in another div with different styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery. The first part of the code is to check the inputs and after checked it should display the checked items the below format. How can do this with the help of jquery.

```html
<ul class="approval approval_scrolltab mt-3">
  <li>
    <div class="approval--member">
      <img src="assets/images/user.jpg" class="user--image" />
      <div class="w-100">
        <h6 class="approval--name">Name</h6>
        <p>Initiator</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input name="one" type="checkbox" id="one" />
          <label for="one"></label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

After checked it should displays in this format.

```html
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 offset-xl-1">
  <h6 class="heading--form mb-2 mt-3 mt-sm-0">
    User
  </h6>
  <ul class="approval approval_scrolltab mt-3">
    <li>
      <div class="approval--member">
        <img src="assets/images/user.jpg" class="user--image" />
        <div class="w-100">
          <h6 class="approval--name">Name</h6>
          <p>Initiator</p>
        </div>
        <a href="">
          <span class="ic-close"></span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried like this.It was working fine for the names but got no idea how can display this user image attached with name and also there is a cancel icon too near the name.I am only being able to display name with this code.

```html
<script>
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var image = $(this).attr('data-image');

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('#checked-names').append('<p data-name="' + name + '">' + name + '</p>');
      $('#checked-images').append("<img src='image'")
    } else {
      $('#checked-names p[data-name="' + name + '"]').remove();
      $('#checked-images').remove()
    }
  });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
With this close  button I want to remove this from checked list(which works great) as well as I want to uncheck this from checked in input.

```
 $('body').on('click', '.ic-close', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
    $(this).closest('li').prop('checked',false) #didn't worked
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script below might be helpful for you. I only added an `ID` to the user-list and removed the `a` tag from the close button in your `HTML`. The `JavaScript` appends the `HTML` you wish with the `name` and the `image` to the list. If you click the `close` span, the item will be removed.

**UPDATE:**
To uncheck the checkbox by closing its user-list item, you have to add an attribute like `data-name="Initiator"` to the checkbox. In the `JavaScript` if have added two lines into the `click listener` of the `ic-close item`, see below.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var image_url = $(this).closest( '.approval--member' ).find( 'img' ).attr('src');
  var name = $(this).closest( '.approval--member' ).find( '.approval--name ~ p' ).text();

  if($(this).prop('checked')) {

    $('ul#user-list').append(
    '<li id="' + name + '">' +
      '<div class="approval--member">' +
        '<img src="' + image_url + '" class="user--image" />' +
        '<div class="w-100">' +
          '<h6 class="approval--name">Name</h6>' +
          '<p>' + name + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<span class="ic-close">Close</span>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</li>');

  } else {
    $('ul#user-list #' + name).remove();
  }

  $('body').on('click', '.ic-close', function() {
    var name = $(this).closest('li').find('.approval--name ~ p' ).text();
    $('input[data-name="' + name + '"]').prop( "checked", false );

    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="approval approval_scrolltab mt-3">
  <li>
    <div class="approval--member">
      <img src="assets/images/user.jpg" class="user--image" />
      <div class="w-100">
        <h6 class="approval--name">Name</h6>
        <p>Initiator</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input data-name="Initiator" name="one" type="checkbox" id="one" />
          <label for="one"></label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 offset-xl-1">
  <h6 class="heading--form mb-2 mt-3 mt-sm-0">
    User
  </h6>
  <ul id="user-list" class="approval approval_scrolltab mt-3">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: great.one problem is I am only getting name always whatever the name is checked.Image is working fine.

Comment: can't we display name with `data-name` only like before

Comment: Ah yes sorry i forgot to say, you have to add the class `name` to the `p` that contains the name. Of course we can make it with the attribute too. Your choice.

Comment: If i uncheck it doesnot remove the items from the checked list and if I do uncheck and check, it re add again and again

Comment: Please click `Run code snippet`at this answer. There it work. So you edited something that it doesnt work anymore. Can you post your full code now in your question?

Comment: ah yes it works when I put `class=name` inside `<p>` tag but i put it inside `<h6>` tag .I need this inside the `<h6>` tag

Comment: I have edited the `initialization` from the variable `name` in the `JavaScript`. Now you dont need the `class="name"` anymore. Please try it.

Comment: One more question.With this close button I want to uncheck the checked items froom input as well along with removing this item from this checked list.I have updated my question can you look through this ?

Comment: Hey  I got little problem here. I am implementing this with django So instead of `Initiator` I used dynamic variable `{{variable}}` .Now the problem is when I uncheck, it doesn't remove the checked items from the `user_list`.But when clicking the close button it removes the item for `user-list` as well as uncheck in the checkbox(which is working great)

Comment: In the place of `Initiator` if I put any thing text it works but if I use `{{ }}` it doesn't works.What might be the reason?

Answer (score -2):

Simply check if you really need jQuery, in 2020 the pure Javascript have the majority of the jQuery fonctions : http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

You can get the checked attribute via an event like this :

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');

// Event Listener:
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.checked);
    if(event.target.checked) {
        // Do want do you want when checked
    }
});
```

I don't understand very well what you expected but I hope that it could help you.

Comment: @freedomn-m it's not an opinion in the code shared on original post, jQuery is not necessary, I simply ask him for check if he really need it. Sorry for the form of the sentence I'm french it seems my words were taken in a different direction than the one I wanted to share.

Comment: Ok I think it's a wrong interpretation of my english which is bad, again it is to say that if he use jQuery just for the original post code it's something like useless (for this code, again, not the library in fact) because it's load a 87kB library for things that Javascript does natively.

Comment: I will edit my post to clarify my bad english, ahah sorry.

Comment: Just look at the html in the question, do you see the very first class `col-xl-6`?  That means they're using bootstrap - not part of the question, but part of the bigger picture.  And what does bootstrap use?  Jquery.

Comment: In addition, modern browsers cache post-parsed javascript, so increasing by 87kb for one page is literally nothing for even a small sized application or intranet application and the post-parsing means there's no additional time after the first page load.

Comment: Finally, you didn't say that jquery wasn't useful in this scenario.  Your wording made your disdain clear that it was never useful in *any* scenario.  Perhaps a language issue, but that's the wording you used:  "useless libraries", not "unnecessary libraries".

Comment: @freedomn-m in bootstrap v5 jQuery is removed, ok there are caching methods but users have to be advised that there is alternative without any increasing of size, currently users tend to use libraries all over the place without really knowing the alternatives.

Comment: And **this is not the place to discuss the merits/demerits or using/not using jquery.**

Comment: Ok I just wanted to advise user that including libs everywhere for no specific reason have consequences.

Comment: Are you really going to open (as of now) **981,211 questions** and stick in "don't use jquery"?  Leave the jquery questioners and answerers alone.  You can filter out jquery questions in your question list if you don't like jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208196/discussion-between-freedomn-m-and-antonin-beaufort).